# how to solve the Defer parsing of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, prestashop-1.7

How to solve the following error:

> 826.9KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

My Javascript code is:

```
{foreach $javascript.external as $js}

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="{$js.uri}" {$js.attribute} ></script>

{/foreach}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix the Defer parsing of JavaScript in prestashop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213288/how-to-fix-the-defer-parsing-of-javascript-in-prestashop)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are adding scripts in the head tag ,you can defer blocking of page rendering by adding the script near closing body tag instead of in header.

Alternatively create a IIFE and load the scripts  after page has rendered

```
(function() {
  function loadJS() {
    var s = document.createElement('script'),
      getScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'script location';
    getScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
  }

  (window.attachEvent) ? window.attachEvent('onload', loadJS): window.addEventListener('load', loadJS, false)
}());
```

Comment: hi i am using async attribute to solve this problem.but solve this issue in chrome browser but it does not work in  mozilla firefox correctly plz tell me how to solve ?? @brk